# Working with php/mysql display information on google maps

Tags: html, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a MySQL address database which contains all the necessary information to look up the address on google maps. Each row with data contains an extra field naming LATLNG. Which contains the Lat and Lng in the preferred format of google maps. ####, ####. I have already created a viewing page with a ‘show’ button to display the content on a separated html page in Google maps with the address above it.

The problem is that I could find all kinds of tutorials (also from google themselves) with the vast possibility’s that google maps provide. The feature I would like to use however isn’t found in a tutorial. And whatever I do, I seem to get stuck with the result of it. 
Example (own database):
After each address field there is a button with the next caption:

```
echo '<td><a href="showgeo.php?id=' . $row['latlng'] . '">Show</a></td>';
```

Example (google maps) what opens after pressing the SHOW button:

```
    <script>
function myMap() {
  var Lelystad = new google.maps.LatLng(LAT LNG INFORMATION);
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
  var mapOptions = {center: TOWN NAME, zoom: 15};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:TOWN NAME});
  marker.setMap(map);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "DISPLAY CONTENT OF ADDRESS ABOVE MARKER"
  });
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
}
</script>
```

What I want is that after pressing the ‘show’ button the latlng from that given address is being picked up by google maps and show it.

Hopefully someonw can help me, if some of the information is not clear enough don't hesitate to ask me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you want to use the JavaScript. There is a very simple API giving you the latitude and longitude through a URL:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=eiffel%20tower,paris

where "address" is the address you are looking for. You must first register to obtain a key and you are limited to 2500 requests per day (but you can store the results in the database).

See full documentation here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=fr

Comment: It's just "JavaScript", no need to yell.

Comment: I've fixed it ;-)